# IIS Monitoring Through Zabbix

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, monitoring, zabbix

I am very new to zabbix and has done some research around the same. I want to monitor IIS and its various parameters.

I understood that by default Zabbix do not provide any template for IIS so I have to configure 3rd party components.

I have tried a number of template as below but none seem to work. I still think I am missing some steps.

I need some solution, if IIS is not monitored then I have to drop Zabbix.

https://github.com/jjmartres/Zabbix/tree/master/zbx-templates/zbx-windows/zbx-windows-iis

https://github.com/vavere/zabbix-w3wp

Answer (score 0):

There is a Zabbix template for monitoring IIS on Zabbix Share: see https://share.zabbix.com/cat-app/cat-web-servers/microsoft-iis . You might wish to check whether that suits your needs.

If you experience problems with the download, please see a similar page at Zabbix.org: https://www.zabbix.org/wiki/Zabbix_Templates#Web_Servers .

Comment: Can you also share the steps to install. I mean Will I just import the template and it will start working or I need to do some prerequisite steps.

Comment: Judging by the item keys this template uses (net.tcp.listen[], service_state[], and perf_counter[]), it should work out of the box.